# Name of Commodore tape format?

Tags: commodore, terminology, magnetic-tape

How did Commodore call their tape format, if there ever was a specific name for it?

OK, let me clarify. I would be interested in the technical term of the encoding as well as any specific name, should it have ever gotten one. Why? I am interested in it. The only terms regarding tape formats I have found are KCS and CUTS, but neither have been used by Commodore.

AFAIK the tape format used by Commodore was identical starting from the PET onwards, comprising all of the 8 bit product line.

I would be interested to learn the correct technical term for the way the data was saved to tape as well.

Comment: *"It must have had a specific name, right?"*   If you've only got one format, "the Commodore tape format" seems like an adequate name.

Comment: Welcome to SE/Retrocomputing! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and clarify by [edit]ing your question: Do you really want to know the **name** of the format? If so, why? Or do you want to know the **technical term** of its encoding? Like FSK, Manchester, ...?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because 
I can’t see it’s point
OP does not seem to have done any research at all,
OP did not look at questions guidelines, 
We are currently under a big flood of dubious questions, 
I’d like to keep the high quality of answers AND questions

Comment: @bugjam Did you forget to log in before editing your question?

Comment: I find the question clear enough as it is. The edit in queue would improve it, but I am not sure this is what the asker meant.

Comment: @user3840170 Wile it's a much better read, it also injects additional questions neither present nor derivative of the original version.

Comment: The OP asks two questions - what was it called, and what was its name?  [Haddocks' Eyes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haddocks%27_Eyes).  :-)

Comment: If pure interest is not enough of a reason to ask a question here feel free to keep the question closed.
As to the amount of research I have done on the topic, please specify how many hours of unsuccessful web search I have to do before I may ask a question, and what kind of proof I have to provide for this activity.
If there is a difference between asking for the name of something and how it is being called, I was not aware of it. As far as I remember I learned that to be synonyms.

Comment: @bugjam - my name is not known here; I am called "another-dave".  But you should read the wikipedia page; 'Haddocks' Eyes' is a piece of humourous writing by an eminent logician, explaining the difference.  Lastly, my comment was intended as a joke.

Comment: Meanwhile, the question is ok as far as I'm concerned, except that you expect that the format has a name, and I can't see why it necessarily should have one - so it's difficult to know how to treat the question beyond the answer we've got saying "there isn't one".  I'm not sure what would provide sufficient evidence of non-existence.

Comment: @bugjam Asking for a name is good as there might be one. Except the way it's written (there must be one) implies a pretext invalidating any answer about it not having a specific name. I haven't voted for closure but I would assume such edgy comment might have provoked negative reception. Now while concrete proof of search is neither easy nor needed, simply starting out like _"I have searched C= documentation around the net, but couldn't find any specific name ..."_ would have easy solved it. Oh, and adding which Commodore the question is about, would have been a great point in any form.

Comment: OK, the question came up on another forum, and somebody stated that he had heard the term a long time ago but had forgotten it since. You are correct, it might be a deceptive memory, as there is no real reason for naming if the format is used purely company internal.
AFAIK the tape format used by Commodore was identical starting from the PET onwards, comprising all of the 8 bit product line. I will add that to the question.

Comment: @bugjam Also, as more time I spend to answer your ever growing question (not a great idea anyway), as more I find all of the requested information not only easy accessible around the net, but already present right here on RC.SE, easy to be found by non-complex search.

Answer (score 1):

> How did Commodore call their tape format?

Hmm, what's wrong with *Tape Format*?

> It must have had a specific name, right?

Does it? If you insist, maybe try **CTF** or '*Commodore (PET) Tape Format*'?

But serious, why should Commodore call it anything if the there is neither a need to distinguish it from others supported formats - as there are none (*1) - nor intend to sell it as dedicated product?

> The only terms regarding tape formats I have found are KCS and CUTS

KCS and CUTS are [two identifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haddocks%27_Eyes) for [the very same format](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/8100/6659)(*2).

- **CUTS** is what Processor Technology named their format
- *Provisional Audio Cassette Data Interchange Standard* (**(P)ACDIC**) is what Byte Magazin, the organizer of the *Audio Cassette Standards Symposium* called the result of that meeting (*3)
- **KCS** is what other (participating and non-participating) magazines (*4) called it - usually to avoid naming Byte being the driver for standardization.

> I would be interested to learn the correct technical term for the way the data was saved to tape as well.

Well, seems less about format - which would be the way data is structured - but encoding. How to call this encoding may depend on your view point:

- **Technical the encoding must be described as an [FSK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency-shift_keying) variant** using sequences of three frequencies to encode a byte using a single full wave each.
- **For all practical purpose it might be better viewed as [PWM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation) encoded** as that's the way the cassette software handles it (*6,*7).

This comes not at least due the way the Datasette hardware accepts and returns the data signal (*5). When seen as PWM, those three frequencies manifest themself as symmetric (50% duty) pules (*8). For a PAL C64 On/Off time is each

- 182.7 µs (2737 Hz) for **S**hort
- 265.7 µs (1882 Hz) for **M**edium
- 348.8 µs (1434 Hz) for **L**ong (or Mark)

For an NTSC C64 it comes to

- 176 µs (2840 Hz) for **S**hort
- 256 µs (1953 Hz) for **M**edium
- 336 µs (1488 Hz) for **L**ong

The difference is due different CPU speed as the signal is software generated. Those ~4% doesn't really matter as the reading routine is made to adapt to accept a way wider speed margin to accommodate different cassette speeds.

Several seconds of 'S' are used for synchronisation - that's the high pitch everyone who has ever put such a cassette into an audio player. Beside that, always two of those pulses form a symbol for data encoding:

- L+M -> Byte Mark.
- S+M -> Zero-Bit
- M+S -> One-Bit
- L+S -> End-of-Data Mark

Only those for are valid symbols, all others (*9) should result in an error.

Further down a Byte is formed from

- Byte Mark,
- 8 Data Bits and
- 1 Bit of Odd Parity

This concludes encoding as used to write the further format.

All of that can be in even greater detail be found at the [C64 Wiki](https://www.c64-wiki.com/)'s age about [Datasette Endcoding](https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/Datassette_Encoding).

---

*1 - That is unless one includes the KIM format - a rather unlikely case.

*2 - As a [rather quick search on RC.SE](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/search?q=CUTS) might reveal.

*3 - Which essentially just adopted CUTS as that standard.

*4 - And Byte Magazin in later years as well. [Georg Jellinek's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Jellinek) *Normative Kraft des Faktischen* at work :))

*5 - Nicely described in the [Encoding section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodore_Datasette#Encoding) of the Wiki page for the [Commodore Datasette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodore_Datasette).

*6 - This goes not only for the genuine Commodore variant but all [Fast-Loader variants](https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/Fast_loader) as well.

*7 - Also the reason why the [.TAP](https://ist.uwaterloo.ca/%7Eschepers/formats/TAP.TXT) format for storing of cassette content is build as a sequence of duration markers.

*8 - The basics are as well Nicely described in [Tommy's answer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/8829/6659) to a question asking *[How did the C64 interface tape drives?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8826).* Which also provides a section about the (block) format.

*9 - These are S+L and M+L - the others would be repetition of the same signal, thus being indistinguishable of a continuous one, making it non-symbols. Although continuous S is used as synchronisation pattern.

Comment: I recall that the Unix file system was called "the Unix file system".

Comment: > Jack Sparrow:
You know, for all that pirates are clever clogs, we are an unimaginative lot when it comes to naming things.

> Gibbs:
[nods] Aye.

> Jack Sparrow:
I once sailed with a geezer lost both his arms and part of his eye.

> Gibbs:
What did you call him?

> Jack Sparrow:
[pauses] Larry.

Comment: I don't think the term FSK is really applicable, since that would imply that data could contain runs of multiple pulses having the same length, but I think that, except within the leader tone, any pair of pulses having the same length must be followed by one which is longer or shorter.

Comment: FSK does not imply anything about how many pulses are allowed in sequence or not.

Comment: @Raffzahn: Generally the notion of "frequency" implies the notion of a periodic waveform.  Given that the a tape has some pulses that occur at fixed times regardless of the data encoded therein, and some that occur earlier or later within that framework, I'd view that as being much more like phase-shift modulation.